# Connection was closed and evicted message with HikariCP after certain idle time

Tags: spring-boot, azure, hikaricp, azure-spring-cloud

My Spring boot application is using HikariCP. I am getting following error message "connection closed and connection was evicted"

```
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase: HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@1610c743 (This connection has been closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
[nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase: HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@1610c743: (connection was evicted)
```

I got this message when I kept my application ON overnight and I tried to access an API from the application after around 10 hours of idle time approximately. The first call after 10 hours of idle time took 11 seconds to return response and gave me above message in logs.
Subsequent calls after this took response time around 2 seconds and I did not see this particular message.
Does any one has any idea why did I got this particular message and why it took so long for the first call after the idle time. My application is deployed on Azure Spring Cloud. Following are the library versions

```
HikariCP version: 4.0.3
Spring boot:  2.5.5
PostgresSql:  42.2.23
```

Hikari property value which I have changed. I have changed this because the default of 30minutes was giving me connection timeout and exception was generated. After changing the maxLifetime property now I don't get any connection timeout exception

```
hikari:
      maxLifetime: 300000
```